# iPhone Tethering backwards

Tags: mac, iphone, tethering

Is there a way to tether an iPhone to a computer (either Mac or PC) so the iPhone gets it's internet from the computer rather than the way tethering normally goes, with the computer getting it's internet from the iPhone?

Comment: You want your iphone to connect to a computer as a hotspot rather than other devices connect to the iphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In Mac OS X it's

```
System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing
```

Share From whatever your Mac's upstream connection is, To Wi-Fi.